# Word doc extension being changed to .bin upon upload

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, mime-types

Word documents that are uploaded with the .doc extension in my application are uploaded as .bin files. Here is the form code:

```
$this->setValidator('upload_report', new sfValidatorFile(array(
    'mime_type_guessers' => array('guessFromFileinfo'),
    'path' => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/reports',
    'required' => $required,
 )));
```

Any ideas why it's doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I think that your class is changing the file name and is not adding the extension...provide more information about this class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony tries to guess the mime type of the file and names the file based on the detected mime type. I've had this problem in the past, and fixed it in my preSave method to move the file.

Comment: That's interesting, the problem I'm experiencing is intermittent, on most occasions the files upload with the correct extension, it's only on random occasions they don't.